# Define search results

Tags: search

I want to be able to restrict what is shown in results page when I search for a word/article. For example, I have an article within a discussion board in a subsite with the title "Sample how to read header values (e.g. vendor number) for invoice row or matching reference on invoice import." When I search for "read header" from the main site I get 3 results, the page that article is on, the container (Discussion baord) that article is on and then the article itself. How can modify search results to only show the article containing the words "read header" and not the page its on or the container its on.
Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you need to explore Search scope, you have to create a search scope and add rule which excludes page and container... below link would be useful to explore search scope.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-scopes-for-searches-65c26a72-f3d3-42ba-8027-1bf7260b6acf

From SP 2013 onwards, Search search is gone but it is termed as Result Sources. Please follow below article to understand and configure result sources.

http://itgroove.net/brainlitter/2013/03/22/sharepoint-2013-search-scopes-are-gone-but-dont-fret/
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sagarp/search-scopes-in-sharepoint-2013-using-result-sources/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this but would you know of any articles directly relating to Sharepoint Online which is hosted in Office 365. That article applies to Sharepoint 2007 and the process might still be the same but the terminology is different which makes it hard to follow. Thanks again!

Comment: Edited answer....please mark it as answer if this helps....!!